# Vim: Appending line from first word, to previous line

Tags: vim

This should be too simple, but I have wanted to know for a long time and haven't seen this question, it's hard to search for.

I often want to delete from somewhere in a line to the beginning of the code on next line. For instance, in C-ish syntax, let's say I want to remove the first boolean in:

```
if (long_boolean_expression1 &&
    long_boolean_expression2) {
  /* code */
}
```

and get:

```
if (long_boolean_expression2) {
  /* code */
}
```

Here I can do `0wdb.` from the second line. (Is there anything shorter or more intuitive? There must be a single command that does `0w` but I can't find it.)

When editing HTML though, nothing seems to work. Whenever I need to do something like turning this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
```

into this:

```
<table><tr>
```

I end up doing it with backspace in insert mode, because all my attempts to do it in normal mode fail, often deleting too much and leaving me with:

```
<table<tr>  <!-- Fail! -->
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try putting your cursor on the `l` and typing `DJ`.

`D` is to delete until the end of line from cursor, `J` is to join next line to current one.

For your HTML example, just try `J` on the first line to join the second line to it.

Comment: Aha! Thanks, that's what I was looking for! It's a bit weird how it inserts a space at the cursor but it's an improvement. And now I know why trying to navigate with Caps Lock on wreaks havoc...

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> joins two lines together.